# Hindi string not supported as an input

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python programming.I want to give Hindi string as an input to a variable in python as:

> > > a='शिक्षा का अधिकार अधिनियम'

On writing this on command prompt I get an error message as

'Unsupported characters in input'

I am using Python 2.7 on windows.Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this problem

Comment: You can get rid of it by upgrading to Python 3.5 or above.

Comment: You need an alternative shell. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105022/unicode-in-powershell-with-python-alternative-shells-in-windows)

Comment: All strings in Python 3.5 are automatically set to Unicode.

Comment: check this it worked fine with python 3.5

http://pasteboard.co/PtbzeLBTG.png

it also worked fine with python 2.7.13

https://ibb.co/ez5jyv

Comment: I am also using python 2.7.13 with nltk3.2.2, but still its not working@Aman Tandon

Comment: thanks...my problem is resolved. But now I am facing another problem. I have two files. from 'word.txt' I am reading strings and want to count occurrence of that word in another file 'document.txt'. The code is as follows:wordcount=0

with codecs.open('word.txt') as p:
 keyword=p.read()

with codecs.open('document.txt') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          for word in line.split():
              
              if word==keyword:
                 wordcount+=1
      print wordcount