# What makes Rich display wrong characters on Powershell 7?

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, rich

I've been a happy user of [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) for Python for some time now, but recently started having issues where colors and special characters are not displayed properly anymore. Here is an example output of printing a `Table` in *Powershell 7 (x64)*.

```
ÔöÅÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔö│ÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöô
Ôöâ Character Ôöâ Binary    Ôöâ
ÔöíÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔòçÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔö®
Ôöé A         Ôöé 0b1000001 Ôöé
Ôöé B         Ôöé 0b1000010 Ôöé
Ôöé C         Ôöé 0b1000011 Ôöé
Ôöé D         Ôöé 0b1000100 Ôöé
Ôöé E         Ôöé 0b1000101 Ôöé
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔö┤ÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÇÔöÿ
```

I did not change my Python or Rich version, and testing with older versions seems to yield the same result. So I expect the issue to be related to some Windows/Powershell configuration issues.

My problem is that I don't know what to look for, hence my question here.
I suspected a misconfiguration for displaying Unicode characters like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105022/unicode-in-powershell-with-python-alternative-shells-in-windows), but it doesn't seem to be the case:

```
PS C:\Users\Thrastylon> [char]0x3a9
Ω
```

Any pointers or explanation of what could be happening would be appreciated.

---

For reproducibility, here is the code I used to generate the table above:

```py
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table


def make_table(n: int):
    table = Table("Character", "Binary")
    start_ord = ord("A")
    for o in range(start_ord, start_ord + n):
        table.add_row(chr(o), bin(o))
    return table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    console = Console()
    table = make_table(n=5)
    console.print(table)
```

Comment: I can't speak for **Rich**, but this is what counts for the usual consoles: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026)

Comment: That... worked. No idea what modified it from the previously working state, but I'm not going to complain. Thanks for the pointer!